Check if any popup is running in 3D viewport
How to check if any popup is running in 3D viewport like adjust last operation menu, not include N-Panel, gizmo

I'm looking for a way to check if it's running to resolve my addon bugs in blender 4.2.
Script for test
import bpy

class ObjectDev(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "object.dev"
    bl_label = "object dev"

    def modal(self, context, event):
        if event.type == "ESC": return {"CANCELLED"}
        print(context.space_data.show_region_hud)
        # print(context.region_popup)
        # always get True/None
        
        return {'PASS_THROUGH'}

    def execute(self, context):
        context.window_manager.modal_handler_add(self)
        return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(ObjectDev)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(ObjectDev)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()

Keymap: object.dev

So far I've tried:

context.region_popup
Run the operator object.dev, it print None, then call a panel, it still print None.
context.space_data.show_region_hud
Same way it always get True


I would check https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.SpaceView3D.html#bpy.types.SpaceView3D.show_region_hud ?

I checked context.space_data.show_region_hud in a PASS_THROUGH operator it always get True

And I checked all attrs in context.space_data, no one swapped when I open a popup.

Are you sure context.space_data links to your 3D viewport ? Where is your operator called from ?

Sure. I run the operator via shortcut in 3D viewport, See script above.

I found that the Adjust Last Operation panel is located in a region of type 'HUD'. The only method I found to determine its visibility is by checking the x and y coordinates of this region. If both x and y are greater than 0, the panel is visible; if both values are 0, the panel is not visible. This is the only reliable method I found to infer the panel's visibility based on its coordinates. The width and height remain greater than 1 even after the panel is hidden, so checking x and y values is the only effective way to determine its visibility. Hopefully this will help you further investigate better methods.
import bpy

class ObjectDev(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "object.dev"
    bl_label = "Object Dev"
    
    def modal(self, context, event):
        if event.type == "ESC":
            return {"CANCELLED"}
        if self.is_adjust_last_operation_panel_visible():
            print("The 'Adjust Last Operation' panel is visible.")
        else:
            print("The 'Adjust Last Operation' panel is not visible.")
        return {'PASS_THROUGH'}

    def execute(self, context):
        context.window_manager.modal_handler_add(self)
        return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}

    def is_adjust_last_operation_panel_visible(self):
        for window in bpy.context.window_manager.windows:
            screen = window.screen
            for area in screen.areas:
                if area.type != 'VIEW_3D':
                    continue
                for region in area.regions:
                    if region.type != 'HUD':
                        continue
                    if region.width > 1 and region.height > 1 and region.x > 0 and region.y > 0:
                        return True
        return False

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(ObjectDev)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(ObjectDev)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()


This is a great help, thank you.

@XY awesome I hope you can find a better solution though then let us know later if you find out :)
